# SQL - Adding columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am new to SQL and was wondering if someone can help me with this small request. I am trying to have my output like down below:

[image]

But I am currently getting this output:

[image]

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT trk_id, 
       cur_state
FROM trk_id_def
Where (trk_id like 'TPA12%' )
ORDER BY trk_id
```

How can I get the columns to reflect MF, CH_A, CH_B, and CH_C with its respective value?

Comment: *Which* SQL? SQL Server? MySQL? MariaDB? PostgreSQL? something else? [Edit] to tag it.

Comment: Please explain the logic of the columns.

Comment: Is `-C` the last possible suffix ? You can also provide a fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) to get help faster.

Comment: This is not how you should store data in a database. You have three things to store: Some track group ID ('TPA12'), some track sub ID ('A', 'B', ...), and the current state ('PROD', 'NM', ...), so store these three parts separately. Don't glue the group and the sub ID to one string ('TPA12-A').

Comment: As to the task: Are empty/MF, A, B, and C the only sub IDs in the table (or at least the only ones you are interested in with this query)? Or can there be other IDs at run time you want to see as additional columns? That would require dynamic SQL (i.e. two queries, one based on the result of the other). Your query already gives you all the data needed. It is usually a task for the GUI (app, Website) to care about the display in a grid.

Comment: And next time please post your sample data as text not as images. Please read [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Med2020 Your query should work fine. Please look into below example and let me know for which data it's failing. I have changed the condition for M column.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table trk_id_def( TRK_ID varchar(50),CUR_STATE varchar(50));

 insert into trk_id_def values('TPA12','PROD');
 insert into trk_id_def values('TPA12-A','PROD');
 insert into trk_id_def values('TPA12-B','NM');
 insert into trk_id_def values('TPA12-C','NM');
```

Query:

```
   select substr(trk_id, 1, 5) as Misti, 
     max(case when trk_id =substr(trk_id, 1, 5) then cur_state end) as M,  
     max(case when trk_id like '%-A' then cur_state end) as CH_A,        
     max(case when trk_id like '%-B' then cur_state end) as CH_B,        
     max(case when trk_id like '%-C' then cur_state end) as CH_C 
     from trk_id_def Where (trk_id like 'TPA12%' )  
     group by substr(trk_id, 1, 5);
```

Output:

| MISTI | M | CH_A | CH_B | CH_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TPA12 | PROD | PROD | NM | NM |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9afb37b12c542f8f4fe574d1bafb4f14)*

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select substr(trk_id, 1, 5),
       max(case when trk_id like '%A' then cur_state end) as state_a,
       max(case when trk_id like '%B' then cur_state end) as state_b,
       max(case when trk_id like '%C' then cur_state end) as state_c
from t
group by substr(trk_id, 1, 5)
```

Comment: yes I am! I changed the code and its outputting wrong data for CH_A and CH_B. `select substr(trk_id, 1, 5) as Misti,
       max(case when trk_id like '%' then cur_state end) as M,
       max(case when trk_id like '%A' then cur_state end) as CH_A,
       max(case when trk_id like '%B' then cur_state end) as CH_B,
       max(case when trk_id like '%C' then cur_state end) as CH_C
from trk_id_def
Where (trk_id like 'TPA12%' ) 
group by substr(trk_id, 1, 5) `

Comment: @Med2020: `LIKE '%'` matches any string. Change `max(case when trk_id like '%' then cur_state end) as M` to `max(case when trk_id = 'TPA12' then cur_state end) as M` to get your query working or use Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur's `max(case when trk_id = substr(trk_id, 1, 5) then cur_state end) as M`.